# Why does Chrome Developer Tools show more than 6 parallel connections from a single source?

Tags: http, debugging, google-chrome, optimization, browser

I'm trying to optimize my site's load time, and I'm looking through the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools.  I must be misreading it b/c it just looks like there's a ton of parallel connections, all from my 1 domain.  (I know I shouldn't have those 304 statuses, could this be part of the answer?)

[image: chrome dev network tab showing more than 6 parallel connections]

Comment: This looks pretty normal. Do you mean the seven different jquery files?

Comment: Well, the timeline looks like there are more than 6 parallel connections to my domain, and I thought that 6 was the maximum limit?

Comment: These aren't connections from different users; each of these are the different files that one request of `events` requires.

Answer (score 1):

The connection details in the screenshot is normal. What is describes is that your HTML page has included multiple image, css and js files which are getting downloaded separately with a separate/reused connection. This is absolutely normal as downloading multiple content serially will cause your site to load very badly.

The 304 responses are also looking normal !!. 304 **(Not Modified)** states that the contents where not downloaded from the server instead the local cached copy was used. This is again a good news for you as it will decrease the page load time.